# Website images links work locally but not on server

Tags: html, css, image

I have a website that has many thumbnail images on it with links to bigger images for each one.
These fullsize images work offline, but when I upload them to the server they will just keep loading.

If I attempt to see the image directly it gives me a 404 error.

This is the website here: www.weissidian.com

What the image looks like when i attempt to go to it:
[image]

I'm not sure why it would be doing this.

Thanks before hand.

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient detail to diagnose the problem, much less provide a solution.

Comment: I'll gladly add more information if needed, but it doesn't seem like it needs much else. It just seems to be a linking issue.

Comment: directly copy the image link to src of the img tag

Comment: What kind of web server do you use? What's the permission of the file on the server? (The server(container) needs to be able to read the file) Where did you upload the file? If you don't know where it is how come we would know that?

Comment: I'm using the website through godaddy, and the website has full permissions. The file is uploaded to the correct folder under public_html. I know exactly where the files are located, and I provided enough information for a solution. No need to be hostile. David gave me the solution I needed, so thank you David for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't specify the URL correctly.  The URLs are case-sentitive on your server and are case-insensitive on your computer.

For instance with `http://weissidian.com/core/img/gallery/fullsize/digital/Shepard.jpg` you are linking to the directory `digital` which doesn't exists. (I guessed because there is no `Forbidden` message.)  When I try `Digital` (notice the uppercase `D`) it works fine.